# Creating index for json attribute

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy with postgres, how do I create an index on an attribute inside a json type field?

This didn't work:

```
Index("tablename.jsonfield.mykey.index", "'jsonfield'->>'mykey'")
```